# How to mention the period of validity of a Schengen visa in the application form?

Tags: germany, schengen-visas

I am an Indian living in Erlangen, Germany. I am planning a trip for my mother to visit me. I have all the necessary documents for applying for her Schengen visa. I would like to know if it is possible for us to apply for a Schengen visa **valid for 2 years**. That is, the validity of the visa is 2 years, but her intended stay shall be 90 days.

I have acquired the Formal Obligation Letter (Verpflichtungserklärung) from Erlangen City Hall. This letter permits me to host my mother for 2 years. I am filling her visa application form now and I don't know how to specify this  "2 year period of validity" in the form.

My question:

Is there a way to specify the period of validity of a Schengen visa in the application form. If not, how do I convey this to the officials responsible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am answering my own question as it may help fellow Schengen Visa applicants.

A few days ago, I had written an e-mail to the VFS Global (that is where Indians have to submit the Schengen visa application) asking them the same question I have asked here. They have finally answered after a week. Here is what they say.

> We would like to inform you that the applicant can apply for the short term visa and can request to the Consulate in the covering letter for longer validity with multiple entery visa, the final decision lies with the German Consulate.

I guess this is the only way we can do that and there is no way to specify that in the application form.