# How can I ask for a UK 2-year visa for a 6-month visit?

Tags: visas, uk, sri-lankan-citizens

I want to request a 2-year visitor visa but will only stay continuously for 6 months in one visit. Where can I choose this option in the visa application?

Comment: Welcome to TSE, Uma. Could you please add to which country you're apply for a visa? If it is to a Schengen country, you could look [at this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/116303/how-to-mention-the-period-of-validity-of-a-schengen-visa-in-the-application-form) to see whether it helps answer your question.

Comment: applying for UK family visitor visa

Comment: Your question says visit visa; why the Family visa? Do you have a relative there (partner, spouse, child, parent there)?  If not, or if you plan to be there for 6 months or less, the Standard Visit Visa might be more suitable. You wouldn't want to risk a refusal.

Comment: @Uma How often would you plan to return and will this be your first application for a UK visit visa? It’s probably unlikely you’d get approval for a 2 year multiple entry visa, they usually look for a good travel history before granting a longer-term Visit visa.

Comment: My children living there I have been there few times on 6 months visa and returned on time. If I can get for 2 years it will save my time visiting to visa application centre.

Answer (score 1):

When you apply for the [UK Standard Visit Visa](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa/apply), either [online](https://visas-immigration.service.gov.uk/alt-language-selection-skip-visa) or [in paper form](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/589170/VAF1-visitandshorttermstay.pdf), you will be asked for how long you want your visa to be valid (6 months, 2 years, 5 years, 10 years). This visa replaced what was referred to as the Family Visitor Visa (among others).

You would be charged the corresponding fee:

- Standard Visitor visa: £93
- Long-term Standard Visitor visa: 2 years £350; 5 years £636; 10 years £798

Comment: Hi I Couldn't see any where in the application requesting to enter how long you want your visa to be valid it is only asking under travel information date you will arrive in the UK and the date you will leave the UK is this where  need to request 2 year valid visa. Please advice me.

Comment: Look at [the form](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/589170/VAF1-visitandshorttermstay.pdf) and you'll see *How long do you want your visa to be valid for?*

Comment: Thank you Giorgio , this question is not on the on line application I do not know why